# Usage of “to be” and “to have been”

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

Why has "to have been" been used in the following sentence? Can we replace it with "to be"? Would there be any change in the meaning if we change it to "to be"?

> Interview was at 10 am and I was not even interviewed even after 3 pm, Human resource team seems **to have been** employed right from a Govt office.

Answer (score 5):

*Seems to be employed* would be understood as a present event or state: "It appears that the team **is** employed from a government office".

*Seems to have been employed* uses the perfect construction to mark the infinitival as a prior action: "It seems that the team **was** employed from a government office".

Comment: Idiomatically, I'd vastly prefer something like *The Human Resources team seems to have been **recruited straight from** a Govt office* (or ***hired***). The word ***employed*** doesn't work very well in contexts like *??Our new Finance Director was employed from a rival company.*